# Selectively boxing and labeling parts of an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, standalone

I want to let these boxes and text-labels fade after sometime, as it would lead to unwarranted cluttering in the image. Also, I want to ultimately put the image slideshow as a part of the beamer presentation.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
 every pin edge/.style={thick,blue!50},pin distance=15mm,
 cir/.style = {align=center,circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=6pt,inner sep=0pt}]
 \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
 {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
 \begin{scope}
        [
          x={(image.south east)},
          y={(image.north west)}
        ]
 %     \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
 %     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north,font=\tiny] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
 %     \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east,font=\tiny] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
   \only<2->
   { 
   \node [cir,pin=20:{Standard}] at (0.55,0.75) {};
   \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.315,0.5) rectangle (0.59,0.87);
   }
   \only<3->
   {
   \node [cir,pin=240:{Standard2}] at (0.45,0.25) {};
   \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.3,0.02) rectangle (0.61,0.41);
   }
   \only<4->
   {
   \node [cir,pin=110:{ABCD}] at (0.16,0.45) {};
   \draw[blue,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.10,0.29) rectangle (0.28,0.6);
   }
   \only<5->
   {
   \node [cir,pin=60:\parbox{4cm}{EFGHI}] at (0.82,0.45) {};
   \draw[blue,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.7,0.29) rectangle (0.85,0.5);
   }
   \only<6->
   {
   \node [cir,pin=20:\parbox{4cm}{lorem}] at (0.65,0.15) {};
   \draw[green,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.6,0.12) rectangle (0.7,0.28);
   }
 \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}`
```

Comment: Please clean up your post ;-) The class is `standalone`, not `stanalone` ;-)

Comment: Remove the `-` from numbers like `\only<2>` and so on.

Comment: <metacomment> What is the purpose of the -?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the boxes one per frame by `\only<slide number>`. If you don't know the slide number in a large presentation, but want to display them one by one, then use `\only<+>`. like in

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \begin{overprint}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
 every pin edge/.style={thick,blue!50},pin distance=15mm,
 cir/.style = {align=center,circle,fill=blue!50,minimum size=6pt,inner sep=0pt}]
 \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
 {\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
 \begin{scope}
        [
          x={(image.south east)},
          y={(image.north west)}
        ]
 %     \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
 %     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north,font=\tiny] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
 %     \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east,font=\tiny] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
   \only<+>
   {
   \begin{scope}[overlay]
   \node [cir,pin=20:{Standard}] at (0.55,0.75) {};
   \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.315,0.5) rectangle (0.59,0.87);
   \end{scope}
   }
   \only<+>
   {
   \begin{scope}[overlay]
   \node [cir,pin=240:{Standard2}] at (0.45,0.25) {};
   \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.3,0.02) rectangle (0.61,0.41);
   \end{scope}
   }
   \only<+>
   {
   \begin{scope}[overlay]
   \node [cir,pin=110:{ABCD}] at (0.16,0.45) {};
   \draw[blue,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.10,0.29) rectangle (0.28,0.6);
   \end{scope}
   }
   \only<+>
   {
   \begin{scope}[overlay]
   \node [cir,pin=60:\parbox{4cm}{EFGHI}] at (0.82,0.45) {};
   \draw[blue,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.7,0.29) rectangle (0.85,0.5);
   \end{scope}
   }
   \only<+>
   {
   \begin{scope}[overlay]
   \node [cir,pin=20:\parbox{4cm}{lorem}] at (0.65,0.15) {};
   \draw[green,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.6,0.12) rectangle (0.7,0.28);
   \end{scope}
   }
 \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{overprint}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `scope` to overlay the marks so that the slide doesn't jump. Corrections are needed for the positions of lines and nodes which I have left out.

Comment: Do the slides have relative numbering in \only? Or do we have to know the slide number in advance?

Comment: @envy_intelligence You have to know them. You have to decide what is shown on which slide.

Comment: Ok, but the image A slideshow is going to be part of a bigger presentation. If there are X number of slides before the Image A, should it be \only<X+1> ? . Please advise me regarding the numbering.

Comment: @envy_intelligence Oh! then use `\only<+>`. I will update the answer.

Comment: No need to load `graphicx` with `beamer` (the class already loads it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, I forgot to gelete it.